# How to add promises in a run method in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

While experimenting with angularjs methods, although I always prefer working in angularjs MVC structure format, but for the sake of simplicity and understanding new concepts in angularjs I was creating a to-do-list with inline js code in angularjs.

While doing that I decided to use the .run() method which I have never used before.

Everything works fine until I opened my developers tools and found that my run() needs promises. I couldn't understand how to add a $q to it as it seems to give an error.

The most accurate version of my file before I tried to add promises($q service) -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="to-do-app">
    <head>
        <title>To do app</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>
                    {{todo.user}}'s To do list
                    <span class="label label-default" ng-class="warningLevel()" ng-hide="incompleteCount() == 0">
                        {{incompleteCount()}} 
                    </span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="actionText">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNewItem(actionText)">Add</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Done</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in todo.items | checkedItems:showComplete | orderBy:'action'">
                <td> {{item.action}} </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="showComplete"> Show complete </label>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var model = {
                user: "Samar"
            };

            var todoApp =  angular.module("to-do-app", []);

            todoApp.run(function ($http) {
                $http.get("todo.json").then(function (response) {
                    model.items = response.data;
                }, function (data) {
                    alert("error occured!");
                    console.log(data)
                });
            });

            todoApp.filter("checkedItems", function () {
                return function (items, showComplete) {
                    var resultArr = [];
                    items.forEach(function (item) {
                        if(item.done == false || showComplete == true) {
                            resultArr.push(item);
                        }
                    });
                    return resultArr;
                    };
            });

            todoApp.controller('TodoCtrl', TodoCtrl);

            TodoCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
            function TodoCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.todo = model;

                $scope.incompleteCount = function () {
                    var count = 0;
                    $scope.todo.items.forEach(function (item) {
                        if (!item.done) {count++}
                    });
                    return count;
                };

                $scope.warningLevel = function () {
                    return $scope.incompleteCount() < 3 ? "label-success": "label-warning";
                };

                $scope.addNewItem = function (actionText) {
                    $scope.todo.items.push({action: actionText, done: false});
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the screenshot with the deployed file and console error -

[image: all the errors are of same nature]

All 8 errors are of same nature.

p.s. I am using angularjs v1.6.4

The todo.json file content -

```
 [{"action": "buy Flowers", "done": false},
  {"action": "get shoes", "done": false},
  {"action": "Collect Tickets", "done": true},
  {"action": "Call Joe", "done": false}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while the data is loading, $scope.todo.items is undefined because the data hasn't come back yet (promises are asynchronous).

The code running in run() doesn't prevent the reset of the application from starting, so your controller is instanciated, your ng-repeat is displayed and your filter is applied, but it tries to call forEach on an undefined variable and will continue to throw errors until the data if present.

You filter code is executed on each angular digest cycle and once the data arrives you will get the expected result.

To fix your problem without changing your structure you could just wait until your promise resolves before displaying your list.

edit: here's a wait to wait for the promise in the controller (there are better ways to do that with services or resolves for ui-router but i'll let you read about those)

```
var model = {
   user: "Samar"
};
var promise;

var todoApp =  angular.module("to-do-app", []);

todoApp.run(function ($http) {
   promise = $http.get("todo.json").then(function (response) {
       return response.data;
   }, function (data) {
       alert("error occured!");
       console.log(data)
   });
});

...

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.todo = model;

    promise.then(function(item) {
        $scope.todo.items = items;
    });

...
```

Then it's up to you how to manage the UX for the ng-repeat, a simple way would be to add ng-if="$scope.todo.items" on your table so that the table isn't displayed until the items are present

Comment: Addon : Or the variable could be checked for undefined before looping through it 

if($scope.todo.items){
$scope.todo.items.forEach( ....
}
to prevent the console errors

Comment: miss, promise.then() function which you are defining in the controller is useless because .then() is used for handling asynchronous requests which i already handled in todoApp.run(), what my problem is while todoApp.run() is waiting for response from $http service meanwhile remaining part is getting executed and hence forEach function is operating on data which is yet to recieve, to curb that unwanted situation i tried to implement $q.defer() but the problem is i am unable to structure it properly as a result controller is giving me error

Comment: the way I described only gives you a way to know when your $http promise resolves, if you don't care when it resolves you can do like Nikhil said and simply add an if in your $scope.incompleteCount

Comment: i am afraid that i have to say you are wrong in that regard because i exactly know when my requests get resolved and i intentionally resolved it before controller and my problem here is i don't want to proceed further until model.items = response.data get executed and in that regard what nikhil said will also not work because that if condition will simply check the condition stated which at the time of evaluation will definitely always be false.

Comment: i will again repeat my problem statement gist - "what i am trying to do is i want to hold the compilation process on run() method until the request is completed and the assignment of model.items = response.data is done."

Comment: @samartajShaikh checking for undefined works (https://plnkr.co/edit/j7ie8vHbIhqvStRYlyrm?p=preview) as far as removing the console errors are concerned

Comment: I presume, once the model gets updated in the response, the digest cycle gets triggered which triggers incompleteCount().

Comment: your code is correct, i got rid of console errors but my purpose is to be able to add $q promises in run() method which is still not resolved.

Comment: digest cycle? ... do angular set watcher on if conditions too ? @NikhilNambiar

Comment: As per my understanding, since incompleteCount() is called in the view , angular sets watcher on that function and all associated variables. This is why when model is updated it calls incompleteCount() as a part of digest cycle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you know exactly your request is resolved; my point is that when you do "$scope.todo = model;" in your controller, your request hasnt resolved yet. You can't delay the execution of your run and that's why i proposed saving a reference to the promise returned by your request. Try adding a console.log at the start or your run, in your .then() callback and in your controller.

Answer (score -1):

By seeing your error we can simply put one length check to avoid undefined error.

```
 <script>
                var model = {
                    user: "Samar"
                };

                var todoApp =  angular.module("to-do-app", []);

                todoApp.run(function ($http) {
                    $http.get("todo.json").then(function (response) {
                        model.items = response.data;
                    }, function (data) {
                        alert("error occured!");
                        console.log(data)
                    });
                });

                todoApp.filter("checkedItems", function () {
                    return function (items, showComplete) {
                        var resultArr = [];
                      if(items.length){
                      items.forEach(function (item) {
                            if(item.done == false || showComplete == true) {
                                resultArr.push(item);
                            }
                        });
                        return resultArr;
                        };
                });
}


                todoApp.controller('TodoCtrl', TodoCtrl);

                TodoCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
                function TodoCtrl($scope) {
                    $scope.todo = model;

                    $scope.incompleteCount = function () {
                        var count = 0;
                       if($scope.todo && $scope.todo.items.length){
                           $scope.todo.items.forEach(function (item) {
                            if (!item.done) {count++}
                        });
                        return count;
                        }

                    };

                    $scope.warningLevel = function () {
                        return $scope.incompleteCount() < 3 ? "label-success": "label-warning";
                    };

                    $scope.addNewItem = function (actionText) {
                        $scope.todo.items.push({action: actionText, done: false});
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: can you elaborate your answer, i think it is the same code which i have posted in my problem statement

Comment: Nope, this is not the same code as yours I put some checks in the code before for loop iteration. like if($scope.todo && $scope.todo.items.length){
........
}

Comment: yes, i saw that and i tried the updated what you have suggested but it still is not working, nikhil's changes on the other hand gave me an error free output,i appreciate your effort.